# How can I use begins_with method on sort key using c# in DynamoDB

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

[image]

If I was to use the high level model, I might try something like this:

```
public async void GetBooksData()
{
    GetItemRequest request = new GetItemRequest
    {
        TableName = "Customer",
        Key = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
        {
            {"UserName", new AttributeValue{S="a"} },
            {"BookNum", new AttributeValue { S = starts_with(queryTerm)} }
        }
    };
    try
    {
        var response = await client.GetItemAsync(request);

            if (response.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                if (response.Item.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var item in response.Item)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Value : \n" + item.Value.S);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (InternalServerErrorException iee)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(iee);
        }
}
```

I need to use the method 'begins_with'  for getting 2 items what UserName is 'a' and the BookNum are book_1 and book_2. This is possible in the high level interface in Java. As an example as to what can be done on the range key in Java:

```
public List<Comment> allForItemWithMinRating(String itemId, int minRating) {
        Comment comment = new Comment();
        comment.setItemId(itemId);

    Condition condition = new Condition()
            .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.GE)
            .withAttributeValueList(
                    new AttributeValue()
                            .withN(Integer.toString(minRating)));

    DynamoDBQueryExpression<Comment> queryExpression
            = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<Comment>()
            .withHashKeyValues(comment)
            .withRangeKeyCondition(
                    "rating",
                    condition
            )
            .withScanIndexForward(false);

    return mapper.query(Comment.class, queryExpression);
}
```

In the low level interface for C# you can achieve this as so:

```
 var requestDynamodb = new QueryRequest
            {
                TableName = "GroupEdEntries",
                KeyConditionExpression = "partition_key = :s_Id and begins_with(sort_key, :sort)",
                ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> {
                 {":s_Id", new AttributeValue { S =  my_id }},
                {":sort", new AttributeValue { S =  sort_key_starts_with }}
            },
                ConsistentRead = true
            };


            var results = await client.QueryAsync(requestDynamodb);
```

where the keys are called `partition_key` and `sort_key`. However, this returns the results as attribute values, which then need to be converted into POCOs one property at a time. It requires using reflection and is made more complicated using converters. It seems strange that this fundamental functionality (as well as other functionality) isn't supported in the C# SDK.
I ended up using reflection to create the tables based on the attributes, when this is also supported by default in Java. Am I missing a high level API for C#?

Comment: You can StartsWith

Comment: @viveknuna I tried `  { "BookNum", new AttributeValue { S = StartsWith("book_") }` but there are error in `StartsWith` with **CS0103: The name 'StartsWith' does not exist in the current context'.** Do I need to use any assembly reference for the `StartsWith`?

Comment: You question is not clear, can you put example what exactly you want to achieve

Comment: I added more code to the post. So what I want to achieve is if I use the `GetBooksData` method, I would like to get MessageBox with  Username **a**'s 2 items (Title and Author).

Comment: Tell us the requirement, it’s seriously not clear at all

Comment: I've got the same issue. I can see the solution in Java. I can do it with the low level model in C#, but the high level model doesn't seem to support that much.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a different syntax and I can't find it documented anywhere (other than in code comments), but this works for me:

```
     string partition_key = "123";
     string sort_key_starts_with = "#type"


     List<object> queryVal = new List<object>();
     queryVal.Add(sort_key_starts_with);

     var myQuery = context.QueryAsync<GroupEdEntry>(partition_key, QueryOperator.BeginsWith, queryVal); 
     var queryResult = await myQuery.GetRemainingAsync();
```